# DbContext.SaveChanges() is not updating the database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to save an entity to the database using entity framework. I have this code which handles the update of the object:

```
DbSet.Attach(entity);
```

Afterwards I call:

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

(I'm using the Unit Of Work pattern with MVC)

The entity I want to add has the state "Modified". Calling the SaveChanges doesn't throw an exception but the return value is 0 and the row in the DB isn't updated. Any idea why this is happening?

P.S. I use the same context to retrieve the entity and then later on to save it.

P.P.S I can post code, I don't know which code would be relevant though because I don't know where the problem originates.

Comment: Did you change the state of the entity *after* you attached it?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach(v=vs.113).aspx), DbSet.Attach resets the state to `Unchanged`.

Comment: If you fetched the entity from the same context it will be tracked - no need to to attach. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: @YacoubMassad no, the last thing I call is the _context.SaveChanges

Comment: Can you attach, modify the sate, and then save changes?

Comment: ok it works now that I removed the attach. Thanks! If someone 'answers' I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that the entity is already attached by being a result of a previous query, or by adding it as a new entity via `Add`.

When you attached the entity via `Attach`, the state was changed to Unchanged.

Quoting from [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Note that entities that are already in the context in some other state will have their state set to Unchanged

Since the object was already in the context, you don't have to attach it. Simply modify the entity and call `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

In Controller

```
ObjEdbContext.Entry(qry).State = EntityState.Modified;
ObjEdbContext.SaveChanges();
ModelState.Clear();
```

in this code `qry` means your updated query......

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one,

```
Student stud = objContext.Students.Where(x => x.StudentId ==     model.StudentId).SingleOrDefault();  
if (stud != null)  
{  
    **objContext.Entry(stud).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);**  
    objContext.SaveChanges();  
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}                
return View(stud);
```

I got this example from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tirthacs/crud-operation-using-entity-framework-code-first/